# Facebook connect showing blank popup on login in Internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am integrating facebook login to my application and it is working fine in browsers except IE. It opens the login window, after login redirecting to http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php, and got stuck there displaying a blank page in the popup. In other browsers it will close the popup and redirect to my site. My application url is like `http://dev.mysite.com/app/`. so I have given the domain name `dev.mysite.com` in facebook application settings. I am using facebook javascript sdk and my site is in PHP. Some one please help me to figure out the actual problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the issue by giving `channelUrl` parameter in FB.init . Now its working fine. Given absolute url to channel receiver. Content of that file will be a single line `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` . Thanks to all :) 
`

Answer (score 6):

If someone is still having problems, there are two things that usually cause fb login problems (it stays open, blank, no response..) in IE:

1. Missing `channelUrl` parameter in `FB.init`.
2. Protected mode: *IE -> Internet Options -> Security tab -> Local intranet ->* (check) *Enable protected mode*

Comment: @Emkas I tried all of the above and I still have the same problem.  Do you have any other suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report : [IE8, getLoginStatus never completes when flash XD is used](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15596) - it sounds like it might be what you are experiencing.

In that case, make sure that your `fb-root` div is not being set to `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` as this will cause the XD Flash not to render.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because of cookies , try to clear cookies.And its not just the problem in IE , its also problem in other browsers.If you test your app again you'll face it.
The best option for it is to use php api , it will take you to the facebook page user will enter credentials and it will send back you to your site again , with string embedded in your url.This is best way without any harm.And easy to implement.

Comment: Till now I didnt get any error in other browsers. I tried clearing cookies and browser data. Still the problem remains. I will check the php sdk.

Comment: @Shameer php sdk will be best.I have worked on it.No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

The custom channel solution provided by @Shameer solved the problem for me. See also the documentation for the Custom Channel URL here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Answer (score 0):

If you use an **AdBlocker** such as **Privacy Badger** (*which I use and love*), it may by default block some external urls like Facebook when opened in a popup window, resulting in a blank screen.

Simply disable **Privacy Badger** (*or other extension*) for that page, or go into the settings and make sure not to block the following urls:

- **www.facebook.com**
- **staticxx.facebook.com**
- **graph.facebook.com**
- **s-static.ak.facebook.com**

That should do it (*hopefully*)!

---

**Extra tip** but beside the point; I found that it's generally ok to ***not allow cookies*** from those URLs, so long as your not blocking the request then the Facebook popup should still work.
It's probably good to try out your app using different setups.

Answer (score -3):

If someone is still having problem with this, the easiest fix is to use the latest API from http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ and publish the .swf for Flash Player 10 (this is the most important part).

Comment: This is not a actionscript nor flash problem