# FB Connect - popup goes blank after login for the second time

Tags: facebook

I am using JavaScript SDK functions for login to Facebook. For the first time, when the user clicks on the login button, the login popup is shown and the user can login. Then the user clicks on the logout button. After logout when the user tries to login again, the popup goes blank after entering the credentials and hitting the login button of the popup. When the user refreshes the main page, it works again.

I have tried the following solution (though it was for IE8) but no luck:

[Facebook connect showing blank popup on login in Internet explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778100/facebook-connect-showing-blank-popup-on-login-in-internet-explorer-8)

I have also tried clearing cookies set by FB. But that did not work. Is there anything I can try?

Comment: hi there, did you ever get a solution to this?