# Website FB login redirects to blank page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm getting a blank permissions page on facebook login using the Javascript SDK. It was working for the last few days and I'm not sure what I changed. I don't seem to be using my app secret anywhere (I do define the API key). Are there any suggestions for troubleshooting? The Facebook debug page unfortunately just had me add some meta tags related to open graph which didn't change anything. I've tried looking at the 100s of other questions like this but can't figure it out. I tried reverting to an older version of my code so I'm pretty sure it's something with the Facebook, but it was working.

The blank page is in the popup window and has something about permissions in the URL. My site doesn't require any permissions though.

This is the URL in the login window after signing in:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=number_I_removed&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D11%23cb%3Df8917d1784b726%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpostacle.com%252Ffd565a0d8d775e%26domain%3Dpostacle.com%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df12565ffe5570f2&sdk=joey&display=popup&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&domain=postacle.com&fbconnect=1&from_login=1&client_id=number_I_removed

If I reload my page I'm signed in correctly. The app ID and Client ID are the same in the URL. Not sure if they should be but wasn't specified a client ID or means of generating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so of course I left out a critical detail: I'm using Django. Further, I'm so reliant on Django I was serving my Facebook channelUrl in a view. Facebook's API didn't like that. After reading the story of a similarly cursed [fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778100/facebook-connect-showing-blank-popup-on-login-in-internet-explorer-8), I changed my ways: URL links directly to channel.html file. No more sorrows.